# Query By State Machine State Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine, transition

I'm using the Transitions gem to create a state machine in my model set up like so:

```
require 'transitions'

class Batch < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Transitions

  state_machine do
    state :pending
    state :completed


    event :change_state do 
      transitions :to => :completed, :from => [:pending] 
    end

  end


end
```

I want to query the model to get all records that have a certain state e.g.:

```
Batch.where :current_state => :pending
```

But that doesn't seem to work, and I'm having trouble finding documentation on this. Does anyone know how to do this? (I'm sure it's possible just can't seem to find it) Thanks in advance!

EDIT

Running tail -n development.log gives me:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: batches.current_state: SELECT "batches".* FROM "batches" WHERE "batches"."user_id" = 1 AND "batches"."current_state" = 'pending'):
    3: <%= link_to 'New Batch', new_batch_path %>
    4: 
    5:                                                                      
    6: <% unless @pending_batches.length < 1 %>
    7:  You have <%= @pending_batches.length %> batches pending on these urls:
    8:  <% @pending_batches.each do |batch| %>
    9:      <%= batch.url %>        
  app/views/batches/index.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_batches_index_html_erb___355556540_17724200__911230187'
  app/controllers/batches_controller.rb:8:in `index'

Rendered /Users/dshipper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@artsicle/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.5ms)
  Batch Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "batches".* FROM "batches" WHERE "batches"."user_id" = 1 AND "batches"."current_state" = 'pending'
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: batches.current_state: SELECT "batches".* FROM "batches" WHERE "batches"."user_id" = 1 AND "batches"."current_state" = 'pending'
Rendered /Users/dshipper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@artsicle/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (6.6ms)
Rendered /Users/dshipper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@artsicle/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (16.1ms)
  SQL (0.2ms)   SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'

  Batch Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "batches".* FROM "batches" HAVING "batches"."current_state" = 'pending'
SQLite3::SQLException: a GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING: SELECT "batches".* FROM "batches" HAVING "batches"."current_state" = 'pending'
```

And running grep 'current_state db/schema.rb' return no results. I would expect that though because there's no actual column called current_state, the state of the record is managed by the state machine (not sure exactly where it's storing the state).

Comment: tail -n 500 development.log, grep 'current_state db/schema.rb

Comment: The command as is does not work (I'm on Leopard) but I changed it to: tail -n 500 development.log | grep 'current_state db/schema.rb' and no results are returned

Comment: it's two different system commands

Comment: edited the original question with results. thanks for your help :)

Comment: don't forget to do a migration and run **rake db:migrate** *no such column: batches.current_state*

Answer (score 0):

I was researching state machines also and, though I haven't implemented it yet in my project, I found this that might be helpful.

1. Make sure your gemfile  includes

   ```
   gem "transitions", :require => ["transitions", "active_record/transitions"]
   ```
2. Make sure your model has

   ```
   include ActiveRecord::Transitions
   ```

   rather than just

   ```
   include Transitions
   ```

   and that it has a column called 'state' as this is where state is persisted.

The problem seemed to have been documented here:

http://dev.netizer.pl/transitions-state-machine-for-rails-3.html/comment-page-1#comment-41

And the documentation on github also outlines the setup for Rails

#### http://github.com/qoobaa/transitions

> ### Using with Rails
>
> This goes into your Gemfile:
>
> gem "transitions", :require => ["transitions", "active_record/transitions"]
>
> **… and this into your AR model:**
>
> include ActiveRecord::Transitions
>
> **A note about persistence**
>
> The property used to persist the models’ state is named state (really!), which should be a string column wide enough to fit your longest state name. It should also be mentioned that #save! is called after every successful event.

Hope this is helpful, good luck!